# Not use docker-machine

Tags: docker

I used docker with docker-machine ( can access container server by 192.168.99.100 ). I would like not to use docker-machine. so I can directly access my container by localhost (127.0.0.1). I shut down docker-machine (docker-machine stop) and tried to build image and container, but It said 'no daemon'. how should I completely shut down docker-machine and use local docker?

Comment: What OS are you on? If Windows or Mac OS, then there is no "local docker" without docker-machine. It needs a Linux VM to run in (managed by docker-machine). If on Linux, please explain what you used as a target for docker-machine (it is not usually used to deploy to the host directly).

Comment: It's Mac, and one of my mac (which never used docker-machine) works well with localhost.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is unset all `docker-machine` environment variables to use you host Docker daemon. This can be achieved with this command.

`eval $(docker-machine env -u)`

Answer (score 0):

There are two different installs for docker on Mac. Both use a VM running Linux under the covers.

The older method includes docker toolbox and docker machine to manage the VM in virtualbox. When you use docker machine to stop this VM, the docker commands have no host to run on and will error out as you've seen.

The newer install uses xhyve to run the VM and various other tricks to make it appear seamless. This is a completely different install that you download and run from Docker, and it requires your Mac be at least version 10.10.3 with Yosemite.

See this install page for more details: https://store.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-desktop-mac?tab=description